# How to display app.config file in mvc

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, web-config, app-config

I have seen some old ways to accomplish this like [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/77917/Read-Configuration-Settings-of-Web-config-using-Ja).

Yet even this display returns:

```
<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["webpages:Version"].ToString() %>
```

I assume I could be using something that is outdated in .Net universe. The goal is to loop through the values and package it back in a log.html page.

Comment: This tutorial which fails at calling the function. and the console application ones I an finding on google, but nothing new to make this work as an MVC app solution.

In example this tutorial is so old it uses <head runat="server" and a script tag to call the function. these just seem like poor ways to develop in c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first of all, 90% of "tutorials" on CodeProject are utter crap, just as the one you link to. The title of it (*"Read Configuration Settings of Web.config using Javascript"*) is a lie in and of itself, as it is definitely impossible to read the web.config from JavaScript.

Second, you seem to be reading ASP.NET WebForms tutorials. Start by looking for an MVC tutorial, preferably on http://www.asp.net.

This is quite trivial using MVC. You create a model to hold the values, an action method that will process the request and a view to display the model's values.

```
public class ConfigurationValuesViewModel
{
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> AppSettingsValues { get; private set; }

    public ConfigurationValuesViewModel()
    {
        AppSettingsValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetConfigurationValues()
{
    // Fill the ViewModel with all AppSettings Key-Value pairs
    var model = new ConfigurationValuesViewModel();     
    foreach (string key in ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys)
    {
        string value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key];
        model.AppSettingsValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, value);
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

And the view:

```
@model ConfigurationValuesViewModel

@foreach (var setting in Model.AppSettingsValues)
{
    @setting.Key - @setting.Value
}
```

Comment: Yes about 90% are just crap on codeProject, but I guess in 2005 that site was great.

Thank you, this is starting to make more sense.